# Направление тега nav

Tags: html

Как сделать так чтобы элементы внутри тега nav шли по вертикали

````
<nav>
 <ul>
    <li>something</li>
    <li>something</li>
    <li>something</li>
    <li>something</li>
</ul>
</nav>```
Помогите пожалуйста!
````

Comment: в CSS добавить `ul{ display: flex}`

Comment: Но ведь они и так по умолчанию идут по вертикали...

Comment: По умолчанию элементы располагаются вертикально, тег <li> желательно закрыть, т.е. <li>something</li>.

Comment: @andreymal, думаю он перепутал.

Comment: @Node_pro не факт, возможно направление сбито какими-нибудь сторонними стилями, о которых автор не потрудился рассказать